# image .show() animation when becomes visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i've some tags like

```
<div> or <img>
```

that i would display with a fadeIn() animation when the user scroll the page and the div becomes visible.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
    $('div, img').fadeIn();
});
```